# No route matches ... missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a sidebar which displays the user's constructions. 
I display it this way:

```
    <% current_user.constructions.each do |obra| %> 
        <li>
          <%= link_to construction_path(obra) do %>
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>  <%= obra.name %>
          <% end %>
          <ul class="nav child_menu" style="display: block">
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Documentos", construction_docs_path(obra) %>
            </li>
            <li>
              <%= link_to "Meus Pagamentos", construction_boletos_path(obra) %>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
     <% end %>
```

It's working with everything, except when I try to create a New Construction, it says:

> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"constructions", :id=>nil}
>   missing required keys: [:id]

I guess that's because it loses track of the current_user.constructions since my controller makes the

```
  def new
    @construction = current_user.constructions.build
  end
```

call... 
How can I pass the current constructions' ids, displaying it at the same time that I create a new construction?

- EDIT -
  constructions_controller.rb

  ```
  class constructionsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    before_action :set_construction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /constructions
    # GET /constructions.json
    def index
      @constructions = Construction.all
    end

    # GET /constructions/1
    # GET /constructions/1.json
    def show
    end

    # GET /constructions/new
    def new
      @construction = current_user.constructions.build
    end

    # GET /constructions/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /constructions
    # POST /constructions.json
    def create
      @construction = current_user.constructions.build(construction_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @construction.save
          format.html { redirect_to @construction, notice: 'construction was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @construction }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @construction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /constructions/1
    # PATCH/PUT /constructions/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @construction.update(construction_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @construction, notice: 'construction was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @construction }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @construction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # DELETE /constructions/1
    # DELETE /constructions/1.json
    def destroy
      @construction.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to constructions_url, notice: 'construction was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_construction
        @construction = Construction.find(params[:id])
      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def construction_params
        params.require(:construction).permit(:name, :locale, :start_date, :description, :image)
      end
  end
  ```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  resources :boletos
  resources :documentos
  resources :constructions do
    get 'construction_documents/index', :path => 'docs', :as => 'docs'
    get 'construction_boletos/index', :path => 'boletos', :as => 'boletos'
  end
    devise_for :users 
    root 'plainpage#index'

end
```

constructions/new.html.erb

```
    <h1>New Construction</h1>
    <%= render 'form' %>
    <%= link_to 'Back', constructions_path %>
```

constructions/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @construction, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
      <% if @construction.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@construction.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this construction from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @construction.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :locale %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :locale %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :start_date %><br>
        <%= f.date_select :start_date %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :description %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :description %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Where is your **New Construction** `link_to` ? And, new should point to `new` action, why does the error message shows you are trying to navigate to `show` action without providing any item `id` ?

Comment: <%= link_to 'New Obra', new_construction_path %>  
I probably have to pass a parameter here, I just don't figure it out which one.  Maybe it's pointing to 'show' action because of this link_to: '<%= link_to construction_path(obra) do %>'.  This link_to is inside the sidebar and redirect the user to his existing constructions

Comment: That's the route:
construction GET    /constructions/:id(.:format)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you add the relevant controller code ,view code that is responsible for this error , routes and server log ?

Comment: Please post your routes file.

Comment: I've updated the question with them